# How to use thread search method in imaplib?

Tags: python, client, imaplib, gmail-imap, email-threading

I want to create a gmail client with the ability to view emails as conversations (threads). In imaplib, there is a method: 
**IMAP4.thread(threading_algorithm, charset, search_criterion[, ...])**
I think it could be the solution. Anybody has experience using it? Please give an example. Thanks.

Comment: You should add the labels 'python' and 'email' and remove 'multithreading'.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

That method is simply a wrapper to the IMAP4rev1 extension THREAD command. Have a look at this link which describes how that IMAP command works: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5256

However, I'm not sure that Gmail actually implements the THREAD command. If it does, it should list 'THREAD=' among its capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Gmail uses an algorithm that is private, and it's not stated in RFCs.

They use a combination of headers (like in-reply-to and references) and considering subject (but in a different way that THREAD=references does).

Comment: Most of what they do is probably covered here: https://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html