# imaplib for retrieving replies to an email

Tags: python, email, imap, smtplib, imaplib

I'm using `smtplib` in python to send emails. I want to fetch any replies to these emails.
Does `imaplib`provide option to search inbox emails using message id of the parent email?
I'm sure it does because that's how email clients like outlook etc. get it done.

I want to do something like the code below -

```
result, data = mail.fetch(None, f'(PARENT-MESSAGE-ID "{parent_msg_id}")')
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Surprisingly, not directly (unless your server has the THREADING extension).  You can search HEADER references and in-reply-to for your parent message ID.   Conventional clients tend to download the headers or metadata for all messages and do the threading client side when using IMAP or POP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879265/how-to-use-thread-search-method-in-imaplib